# MSB4062: The Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AspNetCompiler task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I have AspNet.MVC application and want to build MVC views during the build (only in Release configuration).

I create this target

```
  <Target Name="BuildViews" Condition="'$(configuration)'=='Release'" AfterTargets="Build">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="/" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
```

In `Debug` configuration it builds

In `Release` it fails with error

```
error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AspNetCompiler" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Installing `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core`, adding `UsingTask` and other manipulations doesnt help(

Maybe anyone knows the solution?

```
Target framework - new 4.8

C# version - 8

IDE - JetBrains Rider 2019.3.1

MSBuild Path - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\MSBuild.dll

Project format - Microsoft.NET.Sdk (.net core format)
```

Also, i try to change MSBuild Path (in rider settings)

If i change it to exe-file in rider folder `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.3.1\tools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`, it works

But this is not a solution, because it doesnt work on TeamCity agents, where rider is not installed

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue with the BuildTools in Team City... Depending on what build tools you need there are different paths to it as some exist in `\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\` and some are in `MSBuild\2019\<path>`. For me this issue was resolved by updating my .config towards VS and not the build tools.